# How to get current page number of CarouselView?

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin

I use a CarouselView in my Xamarin project. It has 3 pages. If page number != 1 program should hide some controls. How can I get current page number?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

from the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/carouselview/interaction)

> **Position**, of type int, the index of the current item in the underlying
> collection. This property has a default binding mode of TwoWay, and
> has a 0 value when there isn't any data to display.

Comment: oh, god. It was so easy... Stupid me. Thank you